# Somando valores de 1 Coluna Mysql com codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, codeigniter

Preciso de uma ajuda rápida.
Estou tentando criar uma função no Models, onde apenas some os valores da coluna 'valor' de uma tabela.
Pesquisei aqui em várias perguntas e fiz conforme ensinaram, más não está dando certo.
O código é esse:

```
    function sumContasPagar() {
    $this->db->select('lancamentos.*');
    $this->db->from('lancamentos');
    $somaCP = "SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN baixado = 0 AND tipo = 'despesa' THEN valor END) as SOMACP FROM lancamentos";
    $resultado = mysql_query($somaCP);

    return $this->db->get()->result();

}
```

Se essa função está correta, então não estou conseguindo chamar na View. O código da view está abaixo:

```
echo 'Valor Total R$: '.$cr->valor;
```

E na Controller está assim:

```
$this->data['somaPagar'] = $this->mapos_model->sumContasPagar();
```

Alguém me ajude e de preferência não me negativem. Peço perdão se não estou conseguindo fazer perguntas objetivas, pois estou começando no PHP e não tenho muitas informações.

Comment: Não sei no seu php, mas no mysql você pode altera para SELECT SUM( valor) as SOMACP FROM lancamentos where baixado = 0 AND tipo = 'despesa' , veja se resolve.

Comment: ok amigo... vou tentar.

Comment: GOKU SSJ4, não deu erro, o que me deixou bem contente. Más como faço pra chamar esse resultado na Views? Estou colocando isso: echo 'Valor Total R$: '.$cp->somaPagar;

Comment: no qual esse "somaPagar" está sendo chamado no controller. Más dá esse erro: 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: mapos/painel.php

Line Number: 104

Comment: Não manjo de php

Comment: ok amigo... obrigado pela sua ajuda. vlw!

Comment: @JardelDint você duplicou o questionamento, exclua essa se puder!

Comment: como assim, não entendi?

Comment: Você fez duas perguntas iguais aqui, porque, deixa-la as duas esse poderia ser excluida! Spam entendeu.? as soluções são parecidas na verdade muda o método somente